# Cannot compile Spark Streaming example: getting updateStateByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream error

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-spark

I want to understand Spark Streaming better so i copied the StatefulNetworkWordCount.scala example in its own directory, and pasted it *as-is*, created a simple sbt config file, and tried to compile but it doesnt seem to work. Why is it complaining about the API?
Any idea? The original example does compile fine, but i want to change it, without having to compile the *whole* spark directory like it is set up by default.

thanks!
Matt

```
$ more build.sbt
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.2.1"
urbanlegends-2:streamingtest mlieber$
```

The error:

```
urbanlegends-2:streamingtest mlieber$sbt package
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/Users/mlieber/app/spark2/spark/examples/lieber/streamingtest/)
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/mlieber/app/spark2/spark/examples/lieber/streamingtest/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /Users/mlieber/app/spark2/spark/examples/lieber/streamingtest/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/streamingtest/StatefulNetworkWordCount2.scala:58: value updateStateByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(String, Int)]
[error]     **val stateDstream = wordDstream.updateStateByKey[Int](newUpdateFunc,
[error]**                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Mar 16, 2015 4:23:15 PM
urbanlegends-2:streamingtest mlieber$
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in libraries version incapability. Try to replace `"spark-core" % "1.2.1"` and `"spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.2.1"` with

```
"spark-core" % "1.2.0"

"spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.2.0"
```

*[update]*
**OR**
you also need to add `import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._`

Comment: I've updated the answer, perhaps this article http://blog.scottlogic.com/2013/07/29/spark-stream-analysis.html may give you a proper example

Comment: thanks - however more errors ensued: [error] /Users/mlieber/app/spark2/spark/examples/lieber/streamingtest/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/streamingtest/StatefulNetworkWordCount2.scala:59: overloaded method value updateStateByKey with alternatives:
[error]   (updateFunc: Iterator[(String, Seq[Int], Option[Int])] => Iterator[(String, Int)],partitioner: 
evidence$2:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)])
[error]     val stateDstream = wordDstream.updateStateByKey[Int](newUpdateFunc,
[error]                                                    ^

Comment: The first thing comes to my mind is that the root cause is in updateFunc, however it's hard to say because of lack of information

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by changing the Spark version to 1.3.0.
See my sbt file:

```
$ more build.sbt
import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

name := "Tutorial"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.3.0"
)

resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "resources"

assemblySettings

mergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")          => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")      => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "log4j.properties"                                  => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.startsWith("meta-inf/services/") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case "reference.conf"                                    => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _                                                   => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error while using spark 1.2.0. There is some library compatibility problem. Before resolving this, just tried upgrading to 1.3.0 and this resolved the issue.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.3.0" % "provided"
```